# Shortcut for close Intellij IDEA Javadoc

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

How to close JavaDoc window with hotkey's? I know for open it I should press `Ctrl+Q` when cursor is on class, method, whatever signature. What I should press for close it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the window is pinned (by which you can then close it by conventional means), you can use <kbd>Esc</kbd> to close modal popups, which includes documentation popups.